Usage of StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset with DJL
This is my first model using DJL. I am using PyTorch as the underlying ML engine. I am trying to use the StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset for question & answering pattern. Using the DJL example, I came up with the following code:
public class LstmExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int batchSize = 32;
        Arguments arguments = new Arguments().parseArgs(args);
        if (arguments == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Step 1: Prepare TextDataset for training and testing
        StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset trainDataset = StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset.builder()
                .setSampling(batchSize, true)
                .optUsage(Dataset.Usage.TRAIN)
                .optDataBatchifier(new SimplePaddingStackBatchifier(0))
                .optLabelBatchifier(new SimplePaddingStackBatchifier(0))
                .build();
        trainDataset.prepare(new ProgressBar());

        // Prepare StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset for testing
        StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset testDataset = StanfordQuestionAnsweringDataset.builder()
                .setSampling(batchSize, true)
                .optUsage(Dataset.Usage.TEST)
                .optDataBatchifier(new SimplePaddingStackBatchifier(0))
                .optLabelBatchifier(new SimplePaddingStackBatchifier(0))
                .build();
        testDataset.prepare(new ProgressBar());

        // Step 2: Create your model
        Model model = Model.newInstance("lstm", arguments.getEngine());
        model.setBlock(getLSTMModel());

        // Step 3: Create a trainer
        DefaultTrainingConfig config = new DefaultTrainingConfig(Loss.softmaxCrossEntropyLoss())
                .addEvaluator(new Accuracy())
                .optDevices(new Device[] {Device.cpu()});

        try (Trainer trainer = model.newTrainer(config)) {

            // Step 4: Initialize trainer with proper input shape
            trainer.initialize(new Shape(32, 5, 28, 28));

            // Step 5: Train your model
            EasyTrain.fit(trainer, 2, trainDataset, testDataset);

            // Step 6: Evaluate your model
            EasyTrain.evaluateDataset(trainer, testDataset);

        }
    }

    private static Block getLSTMModel() {
        SequentialBlock block = new SequentialBlock();
        block.addSingleton(
                input -> {
                    Shape inputShape = input.getShape();
                    long batchSize = inputShape.get(0);
                    long channel = inputShape.get(1);
                    long time = inputShape.size() / (batchSize * channel);
                    return input.reshape(new Shape(batchSize, time, channel));
                });
        block.add(
                new LSTM.Builder()
                        .setStateSize(64)
                        .setNumLayers(1)
                        .optDropRate(0)
                        .optReturnState(false)
                        .build());
        block.add(BatchNorm.builder().optEpsilon(1e-5f).optMomentum(0.9f).build());
        block.add(Blocks.batchFlattenBlock());
        block.add(Linear.builder().setUnits(10).build());
        return block;
    }
}

I do not know what will be the parameters of the Shape object in the step #4, so that the block.addSingleton(...) initialization parameters match. I am getting the error as below. Please advise.
18:14:33,120 INFO  ~ PyTorch graph executor optimizer is enabled, this may impact your inference latency and throughput. See: https://docs.djl.ai/docs/development/inference_performance_optimization.html#graph-executor-optimization
18:14:33,133 INFO  ~ Number of inter-op threads is 4
18:14:33,133 INFO  ~ Number of intra-op threads is 4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at ai.djl.translate.PaddingStackBatchifier.findMaxSize(PaddingStackBatchifier.java:141)
    at ai.djl.translate.SimplePaddingStackBatchifier.batchify(SimplePaddingStackBatchifier.java:53)
    at ai.djl.training.dataset.DataIterable.fetch(DataIterable.java:180)
    at ai.djl.training.dataset.DataIterable.next(DataIterable.java:145)
    at ai.djl.training.dataset.DataIterable.next(DataIterable.java:43)
    at ai.djl.training.EasyTrain.fit(EasyTrain.java:54)
    at scs.deeplearning.inference.LstmExample.main(LstmExample.java:63)

